# Sequelize return result is different than console.log(result)

Tags: sequelize.js, return-value, console.log

I am trying to get the full result object that is logged to the console to be sent to Postman through res.send(result) or res.json(result)

my Code:

```
function updateTaskStatus(taskStatus, EmployerId, batchNum){
    taskStatus == "ACTIVE" ? taskStatus = "COMPLETE" : taskStatus = "ACTIVE";
  console.log(taskStatus)
  return models.changes_data.findOne({
    where: {
      Employer_ID: EmployerId,
      Batch_Number: batchNum
    },
    options:{raw:false}
  })
    .then(async (result) => {
      // console.log(result)
      if (result) {
        await result.update({
          Status: taskStatus
        })
          .then((result) => {
            return result;
          })
          .catch((err) => {
            throw err
          })
      }
      console.log(result)
      return result
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      throw err;
    })
```

console.log output:

```
changes_data {
  dataValues: {
    idChanges_Data: REDACTED,
    Create_Date: REDACTED,
    Update_Date: REDACTED,
    Status: 'REDACTED',
    Batch_Number: REDACTED,
    Employer_ID: REDACTED
    Record_Type: 'DREDACTED,
    Plan_ID: REDACTED,
    EE_LastName: REDACTED,
    EE_FirstName: REDACTED,
    EE_TaxID: REDACTED,
    Change_Effective_Date: REDACTED,
    End_All_Deferrals: REDACTED,
    Contribution_Code: REDACTED,
    Deferral_Percent: REDACTED,
    Deferral_Amt: REDACTED,
    Plan_Entry_Date: REDACTED,
    Loan_Number: REDACTED,
    Loan_Pmt_Amt: REDACTED,
    Loan_Goal_Amt: REDACTED,
    Changes_Date: REDACTED
  },
  _previousDataValues: {
    idChanges_Data: REDACTED,
    Create_Date: REDACTED,
    Update_Date: REDACTED,
    Status: 'REDACTED',
    Batch_Number: REDACTED,
    Employer_ID: REDACTED
    Record_Type: 'REDACTED',
    Plan_ID: REDACTED,
    EE_LastName: REDACTED,
    EE_FirstName: REDACTED,
    EE_TaxID: REDACTED,
    Change_Effective_Date: REDACTED,
    End_All_Deferrals: REDACTED,
    Contribution_Code: REDACTED,
    Deferral_Percent: REDACTED,
    Deferral_Amt: REDACTED,
    Plan_Entry_Date: REDACTED,
    Loan_Number: REDACTED,
    Loan_Pmt_Amt: REDACTED,
    Loan_Goal_Amt: REDACTED,
    Changes_Date: REDACTED
  },
  _changed: Set {},
  _options: {
    isNewRecord: false,
    _schema: null,
    _schemaDelimiter: '',
    raw: true,
    attributes: [
      'idChanges_Data',    'Create_Date',
      'Update_Date',       'Status',
      'Batch_Number',      'Employer_ID',
      'Record_Type',       'Plan_ID',
      'EE_LastName',       'EE_FirstName',
      'EE_TaxID',          'Change_Effective_Date',
      'End_All_Deferrals', 'Contribution_Code',
      'Deferral_Percent',  'Deferral_Amt',
      'Plan_Entry_Date',   'Loan_Number',
      'Loan_Pmt_Amt',      'Loan_Goal_Amt',
      'Changes_Date'
    ]
  },
  isNewRecord: false
}
```

what is being sent to postman body:

```
{
    idChanges_Data: REDACTED,
    Create_Date: REDACTED,
    Update_Date: REDACTED,
    Status: 'REDACTED', // note: the task status is successfully being updated.
    Batch_Number: REDACTED,
    Employer_ID: REDACTED
    Record_Type: 'DREDACTED,
    Plan_ID: REDACTED,
    EE_LastName: REDACTED,
    EE_FirstName: REDACTED,
    EE_TaxID: REDACTED,
    Change_Effective_Date: REDACTED,
    End_All_Deferrals: REDACTED,
    Contribution_Code: REDACTED,
    Deferral_Percent: REDACTED,
    Deferral_Amt: REDACTED,
    Plan_Entry_Date: REDACTED,
    Loan_Number: REDACTED,
    Loan_Pmt_Amt: REDACTED,
    Loan_Goal_Amt: REDACTED,
    Changes_Date: REDACTED
  }
```

I am pretty sure it has something to do with raw being set to true, but I am not sure where that needs to be changed.

```
_options: {
    isNewRecord: false,
    _schema: null,
    _schemaDelimiter: '',
    raw: true,
```

I am getting the updated data back so it is not crucial to have all of it, I am just curious why the console.log would show more info than the return and I would like to know how to change it.
Thank you very muchg for your time and considertation.

Comment: Don't mix up `then` and `await` at least

Answer (score 0):

What you see by calling `console.log(result)` is a Sequelize model instance and if you pass it to `res.json` it is serialized into a plain object with model props from `dataValues`.

If you wish to see the same serialized result in `console.log` use `get` method of a model instance like this:

```js
console.log(result.get({ plain: true }))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but what I am actually trying to do is send Sequelize model instance to postman,  or to access specific key values in the Sequelize model instance. Is that possible?

Comment: Ah! I misunderstood you. Then try something like `serialize-javascript` package. Or manually construct an object with desired props form a model instance