# Why sequelize return result different than console.log(return)?

Tags: express, sequelize.js

I try to send the data through postman and the data result is clean(without another property). But when I try to console.log(data), there are many other properties. I read on another thread([Sequelize return result is different than console.log(result)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65441834/sequelize-return-result-is-different-than-console-logresult)), this is because res.json serialized the data into a plain object with model props from dataValues. But how can res.json only get the dataValues property meanwhile the other properties are ignored?

my code:

```
async getItems(req, res, next){
    const data = await Item.findAll({
        attributes: ['id', 'name', 'price']
    });
    console.log(data);
    return res.status(200).json(data);
};
```

postman result:

```
[
    {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "PS5",
    "price": 600
    },
    {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "XBOX X",
    "price": 400
    }
]
```

console.log(data) result:

```
[
    Item {
      dataValues: {
        id: 1,
        name: 'PS5',
        price: 600
      },
      _previousDataValues: {
        id: 1,
        name: 'PS5',
        price: 600
      },
      uniqno: 1,
      _changed: Set(0) {},
      _options: {
        isNewRecord: false,
        _schema: null,
        _schemaDelimiter: '',
        raw: true,
        attributes: [Array]
      },
      isNewRecord: false
    },
    Item {
      dataValues: {
        id: 2,
        name: 'XBOX X',
        price: 400
      },
      _previousDataValues: {
        id: 2,
        name: 'XBOX X',
        price: 400
      },
      uniqno: 1,
      _changed: Set(0) {},
      _options: {
        isNewRecord: false,
        _schema: null,
        _schemaDelimiter: '',
        raw: true,
        attributes: [Array]
      },
      isNewRecord: false
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Sequelize models implement a `toJSON` method which `JSON.stringify` calls under the hood. You can also call `model.toJSON()` to get cleaner logs:

https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/core-concepts/model-instances/#note-logging-instances

Another example:

```js
JSON.stringify({
  toJSON() {
    return 'arbitrary value';
  }
});
// => "arbitrary value"
```

Comment: So when is toJSON method implemented? is it implemented under res.json method?

Comment: The Sequelize model implements `toJSON`. `res.json` calls `JSON.stringify`, which in turn calls `toJSON`

Comment: Oh i see, so toJSON method inside models return the dataValues value. Thanks for the answer bro

Comment: Why i can access directly to dataValues like this `console.log(data[0].name)`?
i thought we must access like this `console.log(data[0].dataValues.name)`?